# Uniqueness with scope in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, unique

I've been trying to find a way to achieve this but I cannot find any attempts even so I am thinking that maybe my approach is completely wrong. That said, what should I do in my **migration** if I want a combination of two fields to be unique? **Please note that I do not want them to be indexes, just database fields.**

For example, for the migration below, I can separately add `unique: true` to the fields, but the combo?

```
class CreateSomething < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :something do |t|
      t.date :datestamp, :null => false
      t.integer :some_number, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you can add a validation in your `Something` model

Comment: As said by @gabrielhilal you need to add validation with scope in your model if you want to achieve uniqueness without index.
For example: If you want some_number and datestamp to be unique combination then add validation as
`validates :some_number, uniqueness: {scope: :datestamp}`

Comment: Try `execute(ALTER TABLE MyTableADD UNIQUE KEY \`my_unique_key\` (\`group_id\`, \`user_id\`))` if you are looking for mysql specific soln

Answer (score 28):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> Please note that I do not want them to be indexes, just database fields.

Indexes are extra pieces on information that the database stores about the columns.
More importantly an index is exactly what you need!

```
class CreateSomething < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :something do |t|
      t.date :datestamp, :null => false
      t.integer :some_number, :null => false
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :something, [:datestamp, :some_number], unique: true
  end
end
```