# Uniqueness validation not functioning as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a `Call` model with the following validations:

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :external_id, scope: :source
end
```

I generate new calls through a webhook that calls the following service:

```
class AircallWebhookService
    include HubspotExtension

    def initialize(params)
        @event = params["event"]
        @params = params["data"]
        @call = nil
        @aircall_number = nil
        @employee_email = nil
    end

    def process
        @call = Call.find_by(source: :aircall, external_id: @params["id"])
        
        if @call.present?
            p "Found existing call!"
        else
            p "Could not locate existing call."
            @call = Call.new(source: :aircall, external_id: @params["id"])
        end

        @call.source = 1
        @call.external_id = @params["id"]
        @call.url = @params["direct_link"]
        @call.direction = @params["direction"]
        @call.status = @params["status"]
        @call.missed_call_reason = @params["missed_call_reason"]
        @call.started_at = Time.at(@params["started_at"]) if @params["started_at"].present?
        @call.answered_at = Time.at(@params["answered_at"]) if @params["answered_at"].present?
        @call.ended_at = Time.at(@params["ended_at"]) if @params["ended_at"].present?
        @call.duration = @params["duration"]
        @call.raw_digits = @params["raw_digits"]
        @call.aircall_user_id = @params.dig("user", "id")
        @call.contact_id = @params.dig("contact", "id")
        @aircall_number = @params.dig("number", "digits").try{|n| n.gsub(/\s|-|\(|\)|\+/, "")}
        @call.aircall_user_id = @params.dig("user", "id")
        @employee_email = @params.dig("user", "email")

        if !@params["tags"].empty?
            mapTagToReferrer
        end
        
        @call.comments = mapComments

        if @call.save
            linkTagToCall
            linkCallToEmployee
            updateHubspotEngagement
        end
    end

    ...

end
```

For some reason, despite the `uniqueness` validation, I continue to see calls with the same `external_id` and `source`.  For example these are 2 records in my DB:

```
[
    [0] #<Call:0x000055d780f639b8> {
                        :id => 8149,
               :location_id => nil,
                  :referrer => nil,
              :consultation => nil,
                :created_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:42:01 EDT -04:00,
                :updated_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:42:01 EDT -04:00,
                 :worldwide => nil,
               :external_id => 582402916,
                    :source => "aircall",
                 :direction => "inbound",
                :started_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:41:03 EDT -04:00,
               :answered_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:41:10 EDT -04:00,
                  :ended_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:41:57 EDT -04:00,
                  :duration => 54,
                    :status => "done",
        :missed_call_reason => nil,
           :aircall_user_id => 567754,
                :contact_id => nil,
                  :comments => nil,
               :lead_status => nil,
                 :call_type => "unknown"
    },
    [1] #<Call:0x000055d780f636e8> {
                        :id => 8150,
               :location_id => nil,
                  :referrer => nil,
              :consultation => nil,
                :created_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:42:01 EDT -04:00,
                :updated_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:42:01 EDT -04:00,
                 :worldwide => nil,
               :external_id => 582402916,
                    :source => "aircall",
                 :direction => "inbound",
                :started_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:41:03 EDT -04:00,
               :answered_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:41:10 EDT -04:00,
                  :ended_at => Tue, 07 Sep 2021 15:41:57 EDT -04:00,
                  :duration => 54,
                    :status => "done",
        :missed_call_reason => nil,
           :aircall_user_id => 567754,
                :contact_id => nil,
                  :comments => nil,
               :lead_status => nil,
                 :call_type => "unknown"
    }
]
```

They are identical and even the `created_at` is identical down to the millisecond.  How is this possible?

Here's the controller in case it's necessary:

```
class API::WebhooksController < ApplicationController
    def aircall_webhook
        ac = AircallWebhookService.new(params)
        ac.process
        head :ok
    end
end
```

Comment: Smells like a race condition. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.  I wonder how I can set that up using a scope

Comment: You can't. You need a DB index as any call from the application to the database is subject to race conditions.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261784/uniqueness-with-scope-in-migration

Comment: Yes. The use of 'scope' threw me off. Thats called a compound or multicolumn index.

Comment: You need to decide what to with the duplicates first like for example removing them.

Comment: ahhhh!  That makes sense

Answer (score 3):

`validates_uniqueness_of` doesn't actually guarantee that duplicate values cannot be inserted. It merely catches most of the cases where users input duplicated data and provides user feedback. Its very much prone to race conditions, and is foiled by stuff as simple as double clicking grannies.

If uniqueness is actually important you need to enforce it on the database layer with a unique index.

```
add_index :calls, [:external_id, :source], unique: true
```

Comment: it gives me this error when I run the migration: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  could not create unique index "idx_calls_external_id_source" DETAIL:  Key (external_id, source)=(529270041, 1) is duplicated.

Comment: remove duplicate entry from DB and try migration again.